# Controller validation error does not appear in apex:pageMessages

Tags: visualforce

I've created a simple page that allows updating/inserting child records in mass. My problem is that if an error occurs during the DML operation it is not displayed in the page. The solutions I've tried so far have not helped.

**Controller:**

```
public pagereference saveChanges() {
try{   
     upsert this.hoursl;} 
catch(DMLException ex){
    ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getdmlMessage(0) );
    ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
    system.debug('Testing Error: '+ex);
       }
     return null;

 }
```

**my page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Monthly_Report__c" extensions="UpdateHoursControllerExt">

<apex:pagemessages id="errmsg"/>

 <apex:form >



 <apex:sectionHeader title="Hours for" subtitle="{!Monthly_Report__c.name}" />
 <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Hours">


     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveChanges}" value="Save"
    rerender="main" status="ajaxStatus" />
   <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" />
   <apex:commandButton action="{!newHours}" value="New"
    rerender="main, errmsg" status="ajaxStatus" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:actionStatus id="ajaxStatus" startText="Updating hours...">
     <apex:facet name="stop">
    <apex:outputPanel id="main">
    <table>
     <tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!headers}" var="h">
     <td class="hdr">{!h}</td>
    </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
   <apex:repeat value="{!hours}" var="a">
    <tr>
    <td ><apex:inputField value="{!a.Project__c}" /></td>
    <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.Date__c}" /></td>
    <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.StartTime__c}" /></td>
    <td><apex:inputField value="{!a.EndTime__c}" /></td>
    <td width="100%"><apex:inputField value="{!a.Comments__c}" /></td>

   </tr>
  </apex:repeat>
  </table>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  </apex:facet>
  </apex:actionStatus>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

Comment: Show us your action (commandButton or Link). Maybe the error message gets passed OK but you `rerender` only a bit of the page so the error doesn't show up?

Comment: @Uri - If you are using the save button, add errmsg to the renrender, also if that does not work try wrapping the page messages in an output panel and giving it the id of errmsgs and rerendering that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you plz replace below code in your VF page

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveChanges}" value="Save"
        rerender="main" status="ajaxStatus" />
```

with the below code and try once again

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!saveChanges}" value="Save"
            rerender="main,errmsg" status="ajaxStatus" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change it:

```
public pagereference saveChanges() {
    try{
        upsert this.hoursl;} 
    catch(Exception e){
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
        return null;
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Adding a return null there won't have any effect.

Comment: As method is called `saveChanges` I assume that this will take user to parent object in future - so last return will return other value, thats why I added this return null in case of exception will occure. But you are right - in this form this won't have any effect

Comment: So the save changes actually just refreshes the page, it doesn't redirect yet. (I might want to redirect in the future but for now just trying to get this error message displayed). I tried the suggested change but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm capturing the error but it is not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code.It is working in my Project.@Artur Kępczyński has sent an proper code but why it is not working for you?I don't know.

I think your VF should be like can you check

```
<apex:page standardController="Monthly_Report__c" extensions="UpdateHoursControllerExt">
<apex:detail />
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pagemessages />
        <apex:pageBlock >
        <!--  Your Own code -->
            </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>


String testerror = ''+ex.getdmlMessage();
    ApexPages.addMessage( NEW ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,testerror) );
    RETURN NULL; 

or 
    ApexPages.addMessage( NEW ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Hard coded text') ); for testing
    RETURN NULL;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but still not showing. I checked my debug log and I am capturing the error message. It is just not being displayed back at my page.

Comment: I modified my code can you check it once.

Comment: Thanks for assisting. Unfortunately still same issue. I tried using your updated code here but still not able to get the error message to show in the page.

Comment: I probably should have shared this from the start then :) - just updated it.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's that rerender attribute on your Save command button. Take that off or add "errmsg" to the list of things to rerender and see if the message displays.